# Why does comparison between empty ndarrays and empty lists behave differently if done inside an f-string?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, f-string

I was messing around a bit with empty `ndarray`s and uncovered some unexpected behavior.  Minimal working example:

```py
import numpy as np

print(f"{np.empty(0)} :: {type(np.empty(0))}")
print(f"{[]} :: {type([])}")

print(f"internal -> {np.empty(0) == []} :: {type(np.empty == [])}")

external = np.empty(0) == []
print(f"external -> {external} :: {type(external)}")
```

Gives the output:

```
[] :: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
[] :: <class 'list'>
internal -> [] :: <class 'bool'>
external -> [] :: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I have three questions about this, and I suspect that the answers are probably related:

1. Why does numpy return an empty array instead of a boolean when comparing an empty array with an empty list (or an empty tuple, or an empty dict, or an empty set, or another instance of an empty array)?
2. Why *don't* we get the same type result when evaluating this inside of an f-string?
3. Why does numpy *not* return an empty array when comparing an empty array with an empty string (`np.empty(0) == ''` returns False)?

Based on the `FutureWarning` that gets raised when trying out the comparison to an empty string, I'm guessing that the answer to (1) probably has something to do with numpy performing an element-wise comparison between iterables with no elements, but I don't really get the details, nor why cases (2) and (3) seem to behave differently.

Comment: np.empty is missing the parens inside the fstring? is this intentional?

Comment: You are making two different comparisons inside your f-string. The second one *doesn't* compare an empty ndarray to a list, but the function `np.empty` itself to a empty list. That means two different `__eq__` methods are involved, not that the f-string itself has anything to do with the output.

Comment: @chepner good observation that certainly explains the results.  But even when you correct the typo there's still a difference.  The external give you an empty array, the internal gives you an empty list.

Comment: @MarkRansom ?? `np.empty(0) == []` produces an empty array in both versions.

Comment: Not in my Python 3.11.0 with numpy 1.23.5.  `f'{np.empty(0)==[]}'` returns `'[]'`.

Comment: That's the string representation of an empty array, not an empty list. `f'{np.empty(0)}'` returns the same string.

Comment: @MarkRansom so does `f'{np.array([])}'`. It doesn't prove that it is not an empty array rather than an empty list. In my python3.12 I get the same result as chepner. (And, I suspect, as you. It is just an interpretation problem. `f'whatever'` being `'[]'` doesn't says whether it is a list or an array)

Comment: Try `f'{type(np.empty(0) == [])}'`

Comment: `np.empty(0) == ''` doesn't return `False` in either context; it returns an empty array.

Comment: (1) is a legitimate question, (2) is just the result of a typo in your code, and (3) is just not true; you may have tried `np.empty == ''` as well.

Comment: @chrslg thanks, now I understand.  It's the difference between `repr` and `str`.

Comment: @chepner It is true, at least that's what happens in my environment (even after correcting the egregious typo).  Comparing an empty ndarray with an empty string using `==` returns `False` and raises: "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison."  As far as I can tell, strings are the only built-in iterables that raise this warning and return False.  I'm on numpy 1.24.1.

Comment: @realityChemist Ah, either I completely missed that earlier, or didn't test in the two versions of NumPy I have installed. The `FutureWarning` is present in NumPy 1.24.2, but not 1.26.4.

Comment: Most comparisons of an array with something else first converts the `other` to array, and attempts an elementwise.  `np.empty(0)` and `np.array([])` produce the same thing, an (0,) shape float array.  `np.array({})` makes a () shape, 0d with 1 element.  `np.array(1)` is also 0d, while `np.array([1])` is (1,).   Comparisons with a (0,) return a (0,) boolean dtype.  The non-elementwise comparison with `''` is a legacy one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform `np.empty(0) == ...`, if the `...` is an iterable, then it will do an elementwise comparison. Since `np.empty(0)` is empty, there isn't anything to compare, so it produces an empty `np.ndarray` with `bool` datatype. It doesn't return `True`/`False` because it would normally produce an array of boolean values, but it is empty.

Regarding the "internal"/"external" comparison, that part is a typo--you're missing the function call for `np.empty` in your "internal" version. Fix that typo and the results will be the same.

Comment: Well the typo is definitely face-palm inducing, oops!  Otherwise a very clear answer.  I guess my only remaining question is why the behavior is different when comparing to an empty string?  Instead of the ndarray it does indeed return a bool, despite strings being iterables.

Comment: (Discussion in the comments under the question has revealed that this behavior is no longer present in more recent versions of numpy, so I suppose it's essentially a moot point.)

Comment: Looking into some of the numpy source code, the [typical equality method](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1ed0bfd3a42bf0c8a0060684645ba97941778006/numpy/array_api/_array_object.py#L475) for a numpy array is only implemented for bool, int, float, or array (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1ed0bfd3a42bf0c8a0060684645ba97941778006/numpy/array_api/_array_object.py#L129) which leads to [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1ed0bfd3a42bf0c8a0060684645ba97941778006/numpy/array_api/_dtypes.py#L58)), with scalars being cast to arrays where necessary...

Comment: ... This doesn't seem to be the route taken by the `np.empty(0) == ""` line and I'm not sure how it works for dictionaries and sets, since those aren't listed in the supported types for promotion, so I'm not sure what mechanism leads to the boolean result here (or why dicts and sets work). Someone who knows more about numpy might be able to answer.